# Solving the heat equation with initial condition $\delta(x-x_j)$

Tags: fourier-analysis

I would like to solve the heat equation

\begin{equation}
 u_t(x,t)-\Delta u(x,t)=0 ~~~ x \in \mathbb{R}^n,~t>0
\end{equation}
with the initial condition $u(x,0)=g(x)=\sum_{j=1}^m j \delta(x-x_j)$ by using the Fourier transformation.

By transforming both sides I get an ODE which leads to
\begin{equation}
\hat{u}(\xi,t)=\hat{g}(\xi)e^{-|\xi|^2t}
\end{equation}

Now using the convolution theorem and taking the inverse on both sides we derive
\begin{equation}
u(x,t)=\mathscr{F}^{-1} (\hat{g}(\xi)e^{-|\xi|^2t}) = (2\pi)^{n/2} g(\xi) \ast \mathscr{F}^{-1}(e^{-|\xi|^2t}) = g \ast K
\end{equation}

where $K(x,t)=(4 \pi t)^{n/2} e^{-|x|^2/4t}$.

In other words, we have that
\begin{equation}
u(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi t}^n} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} g(y) e^{\frac{-|x-y|^2}{4t}}dy.
\end{equation}

What I am stuck now with is how to compute an explicit solution for my initial condition $g(x)=\sum_{j=1}^m j \delta(x-x_j)$ as I do not know how to compute the integral

\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \delta(y-y_j)e^{\frac{-|x-y|^2}{4t}}dy.
\end{equation}

I am very new to the topic of dirac-deltas so I am not sure what to do with them in an integral.

My second approach was to first compute the Fourier transform of $g$, namely

\begin{equation}
\mathscr{F}(\delta(x-x_j)) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}^n} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \delta (x-x_j) e^{iyx} dx \stackrel{?}{=} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}^n} e^{iyx_j}?
\end{equation}

Could someone help me out how to proceed further?

Comment: $$
\int e^{-|x-y|^2/4t}\delta(y-y_j) \,\mathrm{d}y 
   = \left.e^{-|x-y|^2/4t}\right|_{y=y_j} 
   = e^{-|x-y_j|^2/4t}
$$